# Adding a new dll reference to Windows Phone 8.1 project replaces the existing dll

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

The default blank Windows Phone 8.1 template came with 2 default references ".NET for Windows Store apps" and "Windows Phone 8.1". Then I added a new dll "PresentationCore". After this, when I tried to add a reference to dll "System.Drawing",I found that the existing dll "PresentationCore" was replaced with this new dll.
However, the default 2 dlls remained the same. Does anyone have an idea what's going on here?